# adding content above WooCommerce cart page title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add content (an image) above the cart page title in WooCommerce. Is there a hook to do s or do I have to do so in the PHP file?

Comment: There is no hooks for that as you will need to edit the `header.php` file of your active theme, using the WooCommerce conditional tag [**`is_cart()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-8) an an `if` statement, to display your image just on cart page

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

- The question was related to the **Cart**, *not* the **Checkout**.
- Yes, there is a hook. It's WooCommerce... :)

---

USE THIS:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'text_immediately_above_cart');

function text_immediately_above_cart(){ 
     echo "Before Checkout Form";
}
```

---

- **add_action** - tells woocommerce to *do something*
- **'woocommerce_before_cart'** - tells woocommerce *where* to do that action
- **'text_immediately_above_cart'** - tells woocommerce the *name* of that action
- **function** - tells woocommerce what *type* of action it is
- **echo "Before Checkout Form";** - the *actual action* itself

---

Delete  the words inside the single quotes of **'text_immediately_above_cart'** and replace with your own preference.

Then delete the words inside the double quotes of **"Before Checkout Form"** and replace as needed.

---

**FYI, Check out BusinessBloomer's excellent Visual Hooks series:**
https://businessbloomer.com/category/woocommerce-tips/visual-hook-series/
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-cart-page/

Answer (score 0):

I think that could depend on how is the structure of your theme.

Hi, Im New to Woocommerce. 
But I think you can use the hook. `woocommerce_before_checkout_form`
 also, I think that could change depending on your theme. Can you provide more info?
This is a really quick example, and [this is how it shows on my theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRHUL.png)

```
function beforetitle(){ 
     echo "Before Checkout Form";
}    
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'beforetitle');
```

also! You can just edit the page where the shortcode is.

Comment: Will not work for my needs. I needed it on the cart page, and as LoicTheAztec stated there's no hook and I'd have to edit the header file.